# Laravel route:list error returned

Tags: php, laravel, routes

When I try to run `route:list` I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\UserController, 
because the name is already in use in 
/home/vagrant/Code/nomads/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/UserController.php on line 0

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Cannot declare class App\Http\Controllers\UserController, because the name is already in use
```

I have `UserController` under controllers and also `Admin` folder under which is another `UserController`.

I am also using [AdminLTE](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel) package but I have overriden package routes and am using Laravels native routes.

Comment: Rename one of the UserControllers or use Namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Namespace alias ("as") during using it like bellow.

> use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserController as AdminUserController;

Answer (score 0):

Change admin/UserController to AdminController and extend the class UserController if you really wanna do this.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

class AdminController extends UserController 
{
```